# jQuery on() for dynamically added elements, which use stopPropagation()

Tags: jquery

Suppose, we have a few *dynamically added* `<div />` on a page, and we need to bind a click event to each of them.
Normally, we would use:

```
$(document).on( 'click', 'div', function() {
    // ...
});
```

But I need to prevent bubbling up, after these divs have been clicked. So I'm trying to use:

```
$(document).on( 'click', 'div', function( e ) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // ...
});
```

This doesn't work, because the click doesn't reach the document element. I miss live() function, because it could bind events directly to new elements, not to the document.

So how can we make this work? Thank you in advance!

---

### Update

I've found the problem. As Ninsly wrote, the event did reach the document element.

In my app there're a lot of ajax, and I have 2 functions, that are bound to these divs.

The 1st one has the code, that I posted above:

```
$(document).on( 'click', 'div', function( e ) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // ...
});
```

The 2nd one is bound after a div is already on the page, so I used:

```
$('div').click( function( e ) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // ...
});
```

The 2nd one worked, the 1st one - did not. I tried to rewrite the 2nd function in the same way as the 1st one - all works fine now.

Comment: It does reach the document element ([See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kc9L1w9w/)). It stops propagation at the document element instead.

Comment: "I miss `live()` function, because it could bind events directly to new elements, not to the document." That's not true, using `live` the target of event delegation is the `document` object. It was deprecate and removed mainly because of this.

Comment: stopImmediatePropagation ???

Answer (score 1):

return false; will do the trick on this case.

It is the same as writing

```
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropagation();
```

It will prevent the default action for the event and will stop the event bubbling up through the DOM :)

Comment: The event has *already finished bubbling* - the event handler is placed on the `document` object.

Comment: +1 to @Pointy on this - the idea that the event propagation has to be stopped _before_ reaching the parent element in question (and thus you can't simply use `document`) is the crux of the problem.